# How to get all attributes of a product which Start with 'wdb_' in Magento 2?

Tags: product-attribute, catalog, magento2.3.2, product-detail-page, product-tab

I want to get all attributes of a product which start with "wdb_" in custom tab.

For this, I am getting each attribute manually.

> For example: wdb_carat, wdb_info, wdb_clarity etc...

My Code is:

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?> 
<div class="diamond-information">
    <ul class="diamond-info">
        <?php if($product->getWdbMinimumCaratWeight()){?>
            <li class="carat-weight">
                    <h5>Carat:     </h5>
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $product->getWdbMinimumCaratWeight(); ?>
                    </span>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($product->getWdbAverageClarity()){?>
            <li class="average-clarity">
                    <h5>Clarity:     </h5>
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $product->getWdbAverageClarity(); ?>
                    </span>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($product->getWdbAverageColor()){?>
            <li class="average-color">
                    <h5>Color:     </h5>
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $product->getWdbAverageColor(); ?>
                    </span>
            </li>       
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($product->getWdbCut()){?>
            <li class="average-cut">
                <h5>Cut:     </h5>
                <span>
                    <?php echo $product->getWdbCut(); ?>
                </span>
            </li>       
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($product->getWdbShape()){?>        
            <li class="average-cut">
                    <h5>Shape:     </h5>
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $product->getWdbShape(); ?>
                    </span>
            </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I don't want to get each attribute manually.

Can anyone help me to do this?